# Is there a way to create an anonymous object in PHP

Tags: php

Can I get to work a code like:

```
    new \Controllers\ServiceController()->fbdump();
```

so I won't have to create a var just to execute a single method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you need to add a set of parenthesis, since `->` has higher precedence than `new`:

```
(new \Controllers\ServiceController)->fbdump();
```

Comment: Hmm, intresting. Why?

Comment: @Zhigalin If you don't add the parenthesis it will parse it as `new ( \Controllers\ServiceController->fbdump() );` which won't work.

Comment: But why? Why '->' has lesser priority than 'new'?

Comment: @Zhigalin I'm not sure, other than that's just how the, Zend engine, at least, works. It probably was a decision they made way back when they were first working on PHP 4, and just hasn't changed since then. As far as I can tell, it's not even documented anywhere, so the behaviour without parenthesis might change at some point or work differently in some engines and not others. The behaviour with parenthesis should always be well-defined though.