# "Operator" precedence? Why new Object()->method() gives a syntax error in PHP?

Tags: php, object, operators, operator-precedence

Let's consider the following code:

```
<?php

class X{
    public function test(){
        return 'test';
    }
}

//This obviously works:
$x = (new X())->test();
//This does not, syntax error
$x = new X()->test();
echo $x;
```

Why?

BTW:
I know it was introduced in php 5.4

It's not about "how", it's about "**why**" - I know the first syntax is the one documented in the manual. Actually, it's more about where and how to find the answer.

From what I've learned so far, while asking my questions elsewhere:

The -> is not actually an "operator", it's a "token" or "lexical token" - which doesn't help me much.

The first version is equal to saying: "new (DateTime()->format())" which obviously is bad. This suggest it's about "operator precedence", but #1 - the -> is not an operator (right?), and #2 - why isn't this documented anywhere?

BTW, on http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php we can read that the "new" operator associativity is neither left nor right, it's none, and we can also read "Operators of equal precedence that are non-associative cannot be used next to each other, for example 1 < 2 > 1 is illegal in PHP" so... if -> was an **operator** (and it was non-associative) then everything would be clear, but is it an operator? If it is, then why isn't it listed on the above list ( http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php )?

Comment: Related, albeit not very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377118/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-anonymous-object-in-php/34377153#comment57161837_34377153

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Paulpro - seems there is no answer and I just have to live with that :) Thanks again!

Comment: "Just having to live with it" is a typical conclusion with anything having to do with PHP's parser… ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's ambiguous, i.e. it can be interpreted in 2 different ways:

- Call `test()` on a new `X` instance (the one that you want):

  ```
  $object = new X();
  $x      = $object->test();
  ```
- Create a new instance of a class name returned by method `test()` on the object returned by *function* `X()`:

  ```
  $object = X();
  $class  = $object->test();
  $x      = new $class();
  ```

Strangely enough, there's actually no way to write a one-liner for the second case ... the following won't work:

```
new (X()->test());   // syntax error
new (X()->test())(); // syntax error
```

But still, you get the idea.

Comment: The second case is a syntax error because the `(new ...)->` syntax was a hardcoded special case in the parser in 5.x. Since version 7 PHP sports an actual AST parser… is it still an error there? (Too lazy to test right now. ;))

Comment: It is, yes ... I tested before posting. :)

Comment: That makes sense, @Narf - thank you! Well, I mean the first two cases, because as you said, there is still a mystery behind the third case, but that might be another question maybe. Thanks again!