# Instantiate a class from a string returned from function call

Tags: php

Consider the following code which works as expected:

```php
class DynamicClass
{
    public function aMethod()
    {
        echo 'I am the A Method!';
    }
}

class AnotherClass
{

    protected $instance;
    protected $className = 'DynamicClass';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $className = $this->getClassName();
        $this->instance = new $className();
        $this->instance->aMethod();
    }

    public function getPropertyName() {
        return 'className';
    }

    public function getClassName()
    {
        return $this->{$this->getPropertyName()};
    }

}

$aci = new AnotherClass();
```

Is there a way to get rid of the `$className` local variable and accomplish the task with one less line of code similar to the property resolution?

I have tried:

```
$this->instance = new $this->getClassName()();
```

as well as

```
$this->instance = new {$this->getClassName()}();
```

both of which cause syntax errors. I suppose it's not the most important thing in the world. But I don't like to declare variables that will only be used once and don't improve code readability and I was wondering if there is an option I might have missed.

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043166/initiating-a-class-from-string-with-extra-step/58044568#58044568

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initiating a class from string with extra step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043166/initiating-a-class-from-string-with-extra-step)

Comment: `$this->instance = new $this->className();`

Comment: @Cid ahh, I see what you mean. But that is not really what OP wanted. They are trying to instantiate the class using the return value, not a class property.

Comment: I know right, but perhaps OP can get rid of the public accessors and directly use the property

Comment: @Cid I can't get rid of the accessors, I need them to have a meaningful contract. I guess I'm just stuck with doing it with two lines and a local variable

Comment: By get rid of the public accessors, I meant inside the constructor, since you can access private/protected properties

Comment: This was just a simplified example, in reality the class name returning function is called from another class that has the equivalent of AnotherClass injected via constructor, ie:
```class YetAnotherClass {
    public function__construct(AnotherClassInterface $ac) { $this->ac = $ac }
public function instantiator() {$className = $this->ac->getClass(); $instance = new $className()}}```