# Undocumented behavior change in member select and array index precedence in PHP 7 - is this a bug?

Tags: php-7

Consider the following program, based on [this](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/ebb8fc7b58638d9af10c409b113e407a34be2fbb/lib/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php#L1121) code in Doctrine 1.2.3.

```
<?php
class C {
    public function func($p) {
        printf("In %s with param %s\n", __METHOD__, $p);
    }
}
printf("PHP version %s\n", PHP_VERSION);
$callback = array('callback' => 'func', 'const' => 28);
$record = new C;
$repete = $callback['callback'];
$record->$repete(10);
$record->$callback['callback'](20);
```

If I run it with PHP version 5.4.34, the output is:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/xampp1826/php/php.exe foo.php
PHP version 5.4.34
In C::func with param 10
In C::func with param 20
```

Running with PHP 7.4.12:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/xampp7412/php/php.exe foo.php
PHP version 7.4.12
In C::func with param 10

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\cygwin64\home\repete\foo.php on line 12

Call Stack:
    0.0005     403600   1. {main}() C:\cygwin64\home\repete\foo.php:0


Notice: Undefined property: C::$Array in C:\cygwin64\home\repete\foo.php on line
 12

Call Stack:
    0.0005     403600   1. {main}() C:\cygwin64\home\repete\foo.php:0


Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\cygwin64\home\
repete\foo.php on line 12

Call Stack:
    0.0005     403600   1. {main}() C:\cygwin64\home\repete\foo.php:0


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\cygwin64\home\
repete\foo.php on line 12

Error: Function name must be a string in C:\cygwin64\home\repete\foo.php on line
 12

Call Stack:
    0.0005     403600   1. {main}() C:\cygwin64\home\repete\foo.php:0
```

Is this an intentional incompatible change or a bug? I don't see it listed among incompatible changes in version 7. It appears to be an issue with the relative precedence of member select **->** and array index **[ ]** operators. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40633534/467590) notes that member select is not listed among the operators in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). And I note that array index isn't listed either.

So if the manual doesn't specify the precedence, does that mean that changing the behavior silently is not a bug? Either the behavior change itself, or failure to list the change, is surely a bug. Did I miss this change being listed among incompatible changes?

I don't know exactly which version of PHP introduced the change, I only have 5.4.34 and 7.4.12 available to test with.

Comment: FYI: 7.1.33 behaves the same as your 7.4.12 version. Is it a bug? Probably not, since there is a major version change in between.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt Thanks for that verification. But I'd then consider it a bug in the documentation that the change was not listed as an incompatibility. But you spurred me on to check the list of incompatibilities again, and it indeed is listed: Expression $foo->$bar['baz']() PHP 5: $foo->{$bar['baz']}() PHP 7: ($foo->$bar)['baz'](). If you want to post his as an answer I'll accept it. If you don't post it within a couple of days, I'll post it as an answer myself, just to keep things tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spurred on by the comment on the original post from @Ulrich Eckhardt, I went back and read the section on backward incompatible changes in PHP 7.0 more carefully, and found [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect) with its table of old an new evaluations:

```
Old and new evaluation of indirect expressions
Expression  PHP 5 interpretation    PHP 7 interpretation
$$foo['bar']['baz'] ${$foo['bar']['baz']}   ($$foo)['bar']['baz']
$foo->$bar['baz']   $foo->{$bar['baz']} ($foo->$bar)['baz']
$foo->$bar['baz']() $foo->{$bar['baz']}()   ($foo->$bar)['baz']()
Foo::$bar['baz']()  Foo::{$bar['baz']}()    (Foo::$bar)['baz']()
```

The third line in the table is exactly the case that bit me on line 12 of my sample code. So I retract my complaint that it is an undocumented change. Of course I can still complain that it's hard to find cases like this in large, otherwise robust PHP libraries like Doctrine ORM. But I guess that's just the price I pay for continuing to use Doctrine 1 when Doctrine 2 has been out for so long (presumably Doctrine 2 has already fixed any PHP 7 incompatibilities). I'll just tell myself to go sit in a corner.

Since this is basically a change in the way the language is parsed, one could imagine that if one had a parser implementation available it would be relatively straightforward to make it flag constructs parsed differently by PHP 7. Anybody know if such a tool exists? I use RapidPHP as my editor, as well as netbeans for debugging, and both have some capabilities to flag syntax errors, but neither one complains about the code in the original question.